# How do I achieve a layout like this in my Android app?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am a novice android programmer. I am designing my first app, which is a mp3 player. I wish to achieve a layout like the one below

https://m2.behance.net/rendition/pm/12717697/disp/05ec216e30ef24ec7a2cac85a5329140.jpg

This is my preliminary structure:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#33000000"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/_header"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >



</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#74000000"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:id="@+id/_footer"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    >



</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1A000000"
    android:layout_height="478dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:id="@+id/_middle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >



</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

However I am not getting the desired effect. The layouts are overlapping and I have no idea how to fix them. I have tried RelativeLayouts, fragments and LinearLayouts. But nothing is working.

What should I do instead?

Comment: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu, go and use this library

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom [Navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). For Demo Purpose .[NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign](https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign) And [JamsMusicPlayer](https://github.com/psaravan/JamsMusicPlayer)

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, use:

1. a `RelativeLayout` as the root.
2. Header should be aligned at top:

   - `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`
3. Footer should be aligned at bottom:

   - `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
4. Body should be aligned between Header and Footer

   - `android:layout_above="@+id/footer"`
   - `android:layout_below="@+id/header"`

This yields a layout like the following:

[image]

The same pattern can be used inside the Header and Footer to align the items in there, except this time you would align to the right and left of the parent instead of top and bottom. As for the NavigationDrawer, Google has some documents on this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

**NOTE:** You could also use nested `LinearLayout` but this is known to give bad performance ([see here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)).

---

### Code

This xml layout that produced the above image is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HEADER"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="BODY"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FOOTER"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me what changes should be made to make this layout swipeable? So that I can swipe the screen to shift to the next or previous song.

Comment: @AritraBhattacharyya You don't need to make any changes to this layout to do that. What you need is a parent Activity that implements a ViewPager. Google has docs for this: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: I understand viewpager. I have used it with sliding tabs. But this one is a bit different. Here I dont intent to swipe to a different page but load a different song on the same page.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. You should ask a separate question on stack overflow asking each specific question you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a menu (default is hidden, and user can swipe to show it), you should use a `DrawerLayout` as root element. Guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

The second root element should be a `LinearLayout`, with vertical orientation. This layout will contain 3 other `LinearLayout` layouts:

The first one (orientation to horizontal) contains menu icon, title, 3 dots...

The second one (orientation to vertical)  contains contains album image, singer name...

The last one (orientation to horizontal) contains play, pause, next... button